# Tasks are showing in Timesheet although they are expired

Tags: project-server, ms-project, pwa

I have some tasks in old projects with end date 31st march 2017, but still user can see that tasks in his timesheet with wrong start and end date.
How can I remove that tasks from his timesheet?

I have tried following things

1. Changed project status to completed in PWA
2. Close Tasks to Update in PWA
3. Checked Tasks details in Project Pro but seems end date is correct.